# ProgressDialog não sai do 0%

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

estou fazendo um upload de uma imagem para o banco de dados do firebase e quero mostrar isso no progress porem ele sempre fica 0/100.

```
 progress=new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progress.setMessage("Downloading Music");
    progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);



   progress.show();
    uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            double p = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
          int currentprogress = (int) p;
            progress.setProgress(currentprogress);

            if(currentprogress==100){
                progress.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: A variável que está recebendo a atualização do progresso é a variável "p" e não "currentprogress", então, em vez de fazer isso progress.setProgress(currentprogress); faça progress.setProgress((int) p);

Comment: eu esqueci de colocar essa parte,int currentprogress = (int) p;

Answer (score 0):

O **progress.setIndeterminate(true);** faz com que ele não meça o progresso. Muda para **false** que deve resolver.